# Error while getting Active Directory domain name for users using C#.net on Dev Server (Works fine in local)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a method that returns the list for the users and trying to get the fullname based on the domainid. So that i want to populate this list to the Dropdown.

The below code works fine in the **local** and is throwing exception on the **DevBox** that "object reference not set ..." at the below line.

**UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), stringArray[x]).Name;**

Anyone has any solution?

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetUsers()
    {
        try 
        { 
            //Get Users list 
            string usersList = “nraja01,sdaniel01,mmontgo01”;
            char[] charArray = new char[] { ',' };
            string[] stringArray = usersList.Split(charArray);

            List<SelectListItem> users = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var user = new SelectListItem(); 

            //loop through each user
            for (int x = 0; x <= stringArray.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
            {
                user = new SelectListItem();
                user.Value = stringArray[x];
                user.Text = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), stringArray[x]).Name;
                users.Add(user);
            }
            return users;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error("Error occured in GetUsers() method: ", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of a bug in .NET 4.0, you have to use a different constructor for the PrincipalContext when you are using **ContextType.Domain**.  Use this constructor:

```
PrincipalContext(ContextType, string)
```

For example:

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName)
```

See these links for details on the bug:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/4c9fea6c-1d0a-4733-a8ac-e3b78d10e999

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/610995/unknown-principaloperationexception-when-add-userprincipal-in-collection-groupprincipal-members

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to retrieve the users full-name by using this.

`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName`